# Folder/Grouping modules in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, module, grouping, directory, vba

I am working on a large Excel VBA tool for my project. As a result I use a lot of VBA code. In order to make sure I can retrieve everything I already split the code in modules and named the modules with category names such as: Update_Long_Sheetname, Update_Short_Sheetname and Import_Sheetname.

However as the number of modules starts going over 40 I am looking for an way to keep an easy and clear overview of my modules (not showing everything all the time). As such I am wondering, is there a way to group of use folders for VBA modules?

Comment: You can use prefixes on your module names so that they are sorted into groups but you can't actually show and hide groups of them.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Then at least I'm sure.